# batch create columns by lapply and regex to a column in data.table of R

Tags: r, regex, data.table, lapply

I want to get values after some strings, demo as below

```
dt <- data.table(col.1 = c("a1, b2, c3, d4"))
x <- c("a", "b", "c")

dt[, (x) := lapply(FUN = str_match(string = .SD, 
                                   pattern = paste0("(?<=", x, ")([\\d])"))[, 2], 
                   X = x),
   .SDcols = "col.1"]
```

The desirable result looks like this

```
desirable <- data.table(col.1 = c("a1, b2, c3, d4"),
                        a = c("1"),
                        b = c("2"),
                        c = c("3"))
```

I got error message as below:

*Error in match.fun(FUN) :

```
c("'str_match(string = .SD, pattern = paste0(\"(?<=\", x, \")([\\\\d])\"))[, ' is not a function, character or symbol", "'    2]' is not a function, character or symbol")*
```

But I couldn't figure out how to fix this proble. Can anyone give me some hins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop over the patterns and extract the value with `str_match`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt[, (x) := lapply(paste0("(?<=", x, ")(\\d+)"),
     \(x) str_match(col.1, x)[, 2])]
            col.1 a b c
1: a1, b2, c3, d4 1 2 3
```

---

Or with `strcapture`

```
pat <- paste0(sprintf("%s(\\d+)", x), collapse = ".*")
cbind(dt, dt[, strcapture(pat, col.1, setNames(rep(list(integer()), 3), x))])
            col.1 a b c
1: a1, b2, c3, d4 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!  But what does `\\` mean in the 4th line of your code? Also, I'm guessing that my code doesn't work because when there is only one column in .SD, there's no need to use .SDcols. Not sure if that's true.